# RSpec/FactoryGirl Stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm having trouble with what looks like a very simple problem.

So I have 3 models: Foo, Bar, and Lol

- Foo has_many Bars
- Lol has_many Bars
- Bar belongs_to Foo & Lol

Here's the code that's giving me errors.

*spec/factories/foos.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    after(:create) do |foo|
      create_list(:bar, 1, foo: foo)
    end
  end
end
```

*spec/factories/bars.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :bar do
    foo
    lol
  end
end
```

*spec/factories/lols.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :lol do
    after(:create) do |lol|
      create_list(:bar, 1, lol: lol)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to get this test to pass

*spec/models/foo_spec.rb*

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Foo do
  it "works" do
    foo = FactoryGirl.create(:foo)
    puts foo.bars
    foo.bars.each {|bar| puts bar.lol}
    foo.should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of recursion going on with your current factories setup which is causing the `Stack level too deep` error.

In short, when you call `foo = FactoryGirl.create(:foo)`

> factory :foo => create_list(:bar, 1, foo: foo) => factory :bar =>
>   factory :foo => create_list(:bar, 1, foo: foo) ...... keeps looping

Same for `lol`.

You would need to refactor your code. 
One possible solution is as below:

Change your factories as:

```
## spec/factories/foos.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
  end
end

## spec/factories/bars.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :bar do
    foo
    lol
  end
end

## spec/factories/lols.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :lol do
  end
end
```

Update your example as below:

```
## spec/models/foo_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'
describe Foo do
  it "works" do
    foo = FactoryGirl.create(:bar).foo        
    puts foo.bars
    foo.bars.each {|bar| puts bar.lol}
    foo.should_not be_nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation was clear and concise. My only regret is that I only had one upvote to give.

Comment: So I tried implementing this into my real code which didn't work as expected. I made a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237040/associations-not-loading

If you could help me with that one, I would be grateful!